# Filtered from duplicates records to get single record in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to filter the duplicate and get single record from these duplicate.(Phone number column only duplicates not others)

```
For eg:
    row_count   state   phone   areacode    zip
    1           a       123     989         321
    2           z       123     981         322
    3           x       123     982         323
    4           d       321     983         324
    5           a       321     984         325
    6           b       098     985         326
    7           c       098     986         327
```

I want like this O/P:

```
row_count   state   phone   areacode    zip
    1           a       123     989         321
    4           d       321     983         324
    6           b       098     985         326
```

Comment: Which columns are you using to define a record as being "duplicate?"

Comment: Here Phone column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery

```
select * from  table1 t1 where row_count = 
 (select min(row_count) 
 from table1 t2 
 where t1.phone=t2.phone 
 )
```

Comment: Here phone number column only duplicates.

Comment: @Gowtham, modified my answer,  you can check now

Comment: @Gowtham, if it helped you please mark it as answer

Comment: @Gowtham, you need to tick the green sign :)

Comment: Oh, Am new for this site :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach joins to a subquery which filters off all records except those phone numbers having the minimum `row_count`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT phone, MIN(row_count) AS min_row_count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY phone
) t2
    ON t1.phone = t2.phone AND t1.row_count = t2.min_row_count;
```

Here is a MySQL 8+ way of doing this, using analytic functions:

```
SELECT row_count, state, phone, areacode, zip
FROM
(
    SELECT *, MIN(row_count) OVER (PARTITION BY phone) min_row_count
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE row_count = min_row_count;
```

Comment: But in this table duplicate values are the only column phone, not others.

Comment: The queries I gave you will generate the output you expect.  If it's not working with your actual data, then you should edit your question and provide other data.